# How to customize showing NULLs for a given column

Tags: report, interactive, oracle-apex-5.1

In my **Interactive Report** I am trying to customise the way of displaying NULLs for a given NUMERIC column. That is I am trying to display value "NO DATA" instead of default dash "-".

I know there is a way to set this up for a whole report in the Pagination section via '**Show Null Values as**'. The case is that I want to have it customised only for a given 1 column, not the whole report. So I can't use this solution.

Definition of this column must stay NUMERIC and since I can't mix Numbers with Strings NVL is not an option here.

Comment: not familiar with Apex, but in sql you could do NVL(yourcolumn,'NO DATA')

Comment: Since your solution must include in-report fix (you said, NVL() is not an option), you should remove tag "oracle", because you attracting those who would provide you with solution you don't want

Comment: Tag says "Oracle-Apex-5.1". Every reasonable solution is welcome. Removing TAG does not seem to be reasonable advice.

Comment: I agree with you, Janek, about the tag *issue*. Unfortunately, as of your problem, I don't know the solution. It sounds as if you want to learn your goat fly. Why? Because you want to keep column's datatype (NUMBER), put a string into it ("NO DATA"), can't use NVL nor CASE (nor DECODE), so ... what *can* you do? By the way, what's wrong with `-` or "NO DATA" report wise? Good luck with what you are doing. Don't forget to let us know once the goat flies!

Comment: I don't get it Littlefoot. Not only that you did not answer my question, not mentioning that you started your elaborate with "I don't know the solution...", but also you repeated after OldProgrammer solution I emphasised in my post won't work in my case. I'm looking for IR Apex feature, maybe sth. related to HTML expression... I don't know... that's why I asked for help. I am new to this forum, so I don't know whether or not you gain reputation by simply saying stories about flying animals. If yes, please stop that, cuz that's no help.

Comment: Ah - didn't see you comment (you should precede someone's name with "@", otherwise there's no *alert*). Anyway: I'm sorry if I hurt your feelings, I was just kidding, trying to say that - as far as I can tell - you're trying to do something that's impossible (just like you can't teach a goat to fly). The most obvious options, as you said, don't work in your case. I hope that someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!